# 'Sign up' process fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, authentication, clearance

I'm relatively new to rails, so please keep this in mind when answering. :)

I've added the `clearance` gem to my rails app. I executed `rails g clearance:views`, no hassles. Next I executed `rails g clearance:specs`. All the clearance specs pass except for one:

`/spec/features/clearance/visitor_signs_up_spec.rb:13 # Visitor signs up with valid email and password`

Here's the rspec error message:

`` Visitor signs up with valid email and password
     Failure/Error: expect_user_to_be_signed_in
       expected to find button "Sign out" but there were no matches
     # ./spec/support/features/clearance_helpers.rb:35:in `expect_user_to_be_signed_in'
     # ./spec/features/clearance/visitor_signs_up_spec.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # -e:1:in `<main>' ``

Interestingly, when I attempt to follow the spec manually, the sign up process completes but it doesn't create a new session. In other words, I have to sign in after signing up. This appears to match the behavior that occurs in `/spec/features/clearance/visitor_signs_up_spec.rb:13`, although it's not the expected behavior, according to that spec.

None of the other specs that use the same method, `expect_user_to_be_signed_in`, have this problem.

Also, my rails server log doesn't indicate any errors.

I don't know where else to look to narrow down the problem. What do you think?

UPDATE: Found an error!

```
Started POST "/users" for ::1 at 2015-10-18 15:15:44 -0600
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"first_name"=>"Michael", "last_name"=>"Hargiss", "username"=>"mycargus", "email"=>"valid@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Sign up"}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/sign_in
Filter chain halted as :require_login rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

UPDATE: I fixed the previous error by changing the redirect url after successfully saving a new user. I also had to add the following to my `UsersController`:

```
before_action :require_login, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Still can't get it to sign in automatically after signing up. Instead I implemented a workaround inside `Users#create`:

```
if @user.save
  format.html { redirect_to sign_in_path, notice: "Welcome, #{@user.first_name}!\nSign in to continue." }

  ...

end
```